# android How to save and display data into two different activity in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am doing an android project with a list of college and onClicking to this list displays the college details.

Here are the snapshots:

- [Schools list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYNz9.png)
- [School detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcYCQ.png)

At the right top end of schools detail on the toolbar,I have set a small star looking icon.On clicking to that icon the icons gets changed to filled icon and the name of that school is shaved to bookmark class in the form of list.Now I wish to store the details tooo.I mean On clicking to that bookmarked list item I want to store & display the details too same as SchoolDetails class.I am wandering how can I do so using sqlite database.Please give me some direction on how can I do that.

This is my bookmark class

```
public class Bookmark extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Bookmarkitem> ourBookmarkListItems = new ArrayList<Bookmarkitem>();
    private ListView listView;
    private BookmarkAdapter adapter;
    DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookmark);
        dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Bookmark");

        List<Bookmarkitem> bookmarkedSchools = dbhelper.getAllSchoolBookmark();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_bookmarked);
        if (bookmarkedSchools.size() != 0) {
            adapter = new BookmarkAdapter(this, bookmarkedSchools);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have no bookmark yet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Bookmark.this, SchoolDetails.class);

                startActivity(i);

            }
        });


    }
```

and this is my database class that now just stores the name,logo and address of school.

```
      package com.example.user.educationhunt.database;

import android.accessibilityservice.GestureDescription;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.user.educationhunt.listner.DatabaseUpdatedListener;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos.Bookmarkitem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by user on 11/22/2016.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseUpdatedListener databaseUpdatedListener;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BookmarkDatabase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK = "bookmark";

    //    Contact table columns name
    private static final String ID = "Id";
    private static final String SID = "SId";
    private static final String NAME = "Name";
    private static final String LOGO = "Logo";
    private static final String LOCATION = "Location";

    String createTableBookmark = "Create table if not exists `Bookmark` ("
            + "`name`   TEXT," + "`location`    TEXT," + "`logo`    TEXT);";

    String CREATE_SCHOOL_BOOKMARK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK + "("
            + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + SID + " INTEGER, "
            + NAME + " TEXT, "
            + LOGO + " TEXT, "
            + LOCATION + " TEXT " + ")";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void insertBookmarkData(Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put("name", bookmarkitem.name);
        content.put("location", bookmarkitem.address);
        content.put("logo", bookmarkitem.logo);

        db.insert("Bookmark", null, content);
    }

    public ArrayList<Bookmarkitem> getBookmarkist() {
        String sql = "select * from Bookmark ";
        ArrayList<Bookmarkitem> bookmarklist = new ArrayList<Bookmarkitem>();

        Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Bookmarkitem info = new Bookmarkitem();
            info.name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            info.address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("location"));
            info.logo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("logo"));
            bookmarklist.add(info);
        }
        c.close();
        return bookmarklist;
    }

    public Bookmarkitem getBookmarkData(String bookmarkName) {
        String sql = "select * from Bookmark  where id='" + bookmarkName + "'";

        Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Bookmarkitem info = new Bookmarkitem();
            info.name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            info.address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("location"));
            info.logo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("logo"));
        }
        c.close();
        Bookmarkitem info = null;
        return info;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_SCHOOL_BOOKMARK_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public void addSchoolBookmark(Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem, MenuItem menuItem) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SID, bookmarkitem.getBookmarkID());
        values.put(NAME, bookmarkitem.getName());
        values.put(LOGO, bookmarkitem.getLogo());
        values.put(LOCATION, bookmarkitem.getAddress());

        //inserting row
        if (db.insert(TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK, null, values) != -1) {
            databaseUpdatedListener.setDatabaseSuccess(bookmarkitem.getName(), menuItem);
        } else {
            databaseUpdatedListener.setDatabaseError("Failed to insert");
        }
        db.close();
    }

    public List<Bookmarkitem> getAllSchoolBookmark() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK;
        List<Bookmarkitem> bookmarkitems = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem = new Bookmarkitem();
                bookmarkitem.setBookmarkID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                bookmarkitem.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                bookmarkitem.setLogo(cursor.getString(2));
                bookmarkitem.setAddress(cursor.getString(3));
                bookmarkitems.add(bookmarkitem);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return bookmarkitems;
    }

    public void removeBookmarkItem(int sID) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK + " WHERE " + SID+ "= '" + sID+ "'");
        db.close();


    }
}
```

This is my SchoolDetails class

```
package com.example.user.educationhunt;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.user.educationhunt.database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.fragment.About;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.fragment.Admission;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.fragment.FeeStructure;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.listner.DatabaseUpdatedListener;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos.Bookmarkitem;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos.OurSchool;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SchoolDetails extends AppCompatActivity implements DatabaseUpdatedListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    Boolean isStarFilled = false;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    OurSchool ourSchool;
    private Menu menu;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_school_details);

        ourSchool = (OurSchool) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("school");

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(ourSchool.getSchoolName());


        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        db.databaseUpdatedListener = this;

        Toast.makeText(this, ourSchool.getSchoolName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fav_school, menu);
        this.menu = menu;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.star_School:
                Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem = new Bookmarkitem();
                bookmarkitem.setBookmarkID(ourSchool.getSchoolId());
                bookmarkitem.setName(ourSchool.getSchoolName());
                bookmarkitem.setLogo(ourSchool.getSchoolLogo());
                bookmarkitem.setAddress(ourSchool.getSchoolAddress());
                db.addSchoolBookmark(bookmarkitem, item);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        List<Bookmarkitem> bookmarkitems = db.getAllSchoolBookmark();
        if (bookmarkitems.size() != 0) {
            for (Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem : bookmarkitems) {
                if (bookmarkitem.getBookmarkID() == ourSchool.getSchoolId()) {
                    isStarFilled = true;
                    break;
                }
                else isStarFilled=false;
            }
            if (isStarFilled) {
                menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.starfilled));
            }else if (isStarFilled.booleanValue()==true){
                delete();
                menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.star));
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void delete(){
        List<Bookmarkitem> bookmarkitems = db.getAllSchoolBookmark();
        db.removeBookmarkItem(ourSchool.getSchoolId());    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new About(), "ABOUT US");
        adapter.addFragment(new Admission(), "ADMISSION");
        adapter.addFragment(new FeeStructure(), "FEE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void setDatabaseSuccess(String schoolName, MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(this, schoolName + "successfully added as bookmark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        item.setIcon(R.mipmap.starfilled);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDatabaseError(String failureMessage) {
        Toast.makeText(this, failureMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will be heartly welcomed

Comment: in your sqlite db, save school detais with same id. and again fetch same id data and display it.

Comment: Should I have to make a different database or I can use the add the details field to same database

Comment: just create new table in same database

Comment: Divyesh bro thanks for the advice,can you please help me to delete the bookmarked item.I mean when I click to the bookmark icon then the bookmarked list item should be deleted from the bookmark list

Comment: when you click on bookmark icon, get your item position and from that position, get school id. Now, in your bookmarked list check for that id and remove it from list

Comment: Can you please edit it in my code above

Comment: where is your bookmark click action?

Comment: Its inside SchoolDetails class.I have updated that in my question .Please have a look

Comment: but, where is click? when do you want to delete item from bookmarked list?

Comment: I want to delete item from bookmarklist.To do this first I want to do this by two method.First is by longclicking on the bookmark list item and second is when i open the school details and the star is filled.I want to click it one more time so that star becomes blank and the corresponding item will be deleted from the bookmarklist.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final int ID = "Id";
private static final int SID = "SId";
private static final String NAME = "Name";
private static final String LOGO = "Logo";
private static final String LOCATION = "Location";
```

Change create table code:

```
  String CREATE_SCHOOL_BOOKMARK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK + "("
                + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + SID + " INTEGER, "
                + NAME + " TEXT, "
                + LOGO + " TEXT, "
                + LOCATION + " TEXT " + ")";
```

ALso change this:

```
public void addSchoolBookmark(Bookmarkitem bookmarkitem, MenuItem menuItem) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SID, bookmarkitem.getBookmarkID());
        values.put(NAME, bookmarkitem.getName());
        values.put(LOGO, bookmarkitem.getLogo());
        values.put(LOCATION, bookmarkitem.getAddress());

        //inserting row
        if (db.insert(TABLE_NAME_BOOKMARK, null, values) != -1) {
            databaseUpdatedListener.setDatabaseSuccess(bookmarkitem.getName(), menuItem);
        } else {
            databaseUpdatedListener.setDatabaseError("Failed to insert");
        }
        db.close();
    }
```

first create method in SCHOOL class to remove entry from bookmark table:

```
            db.removeBookmarkItem(ourSchool.getSchoolId(), item);
```

Now, in database class: implement above method to delete record:

```
public void removeBookmarkItem(int sID) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();



   database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + SID+ "= '" + sID+ "'");
db.close();


}
```

Same method is used in both cases, you need to check if item is already bookmarked then send that id to remove method and your data is removed

Comment: what is happening when you remove record from  that id?

Comment: not even a single change,have u checked my code above?I may have messed.Plz have a looked

Comment: you are not inserting school id in your bookmark table. so just change remove method as i updated above.

Comment: Dear sir in removeBookmarkItem method inside database class you have included only 1 paramater however during the function call in School class you have included 2 parameters,This generates error in my second parameter "item".When i removed that item from code its shows no error bt on running the app shows no any change just like above

Comment: db.insert("Bookmark", null, content); change to bookmark

Comment: Bro,result even turned worse,as per your suggestions now even I couldn't save my data into list now

Comment: you do not need to pass ID because it is auto increament, just pass schoolid,name,logo,address

Comment: None of the above suggestions worked.Anyway thanx alot for your time and consideration