# Unable to arrange android tabs in a proper sequence

Tags: android, tabs

Hello all I simply want to achieve this.But I am not being able to achieve this

[image: Tab design]

I did this to achieve this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#42474b"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarlogo"
                android:src="@mipmap/toolbarlogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                 />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#494e51"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="The Ongoing survey closes on Dec 31,2016 at 2:00pm GMT"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="#fff"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:background="@drawable/innerpg_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is my class file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ongoing,
            R.drawable.upcoming,
            R.drawable.results
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

        for(int i=0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            View tab = ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(i);
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) tab.getLayoutParams();
            p.setMargins(10, 10, 50, 30);
            tab.requestLayout();
        }

    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new Ongoing(), "Ongoing");
        adapter.addFrag(new Upcomming(), "Upcomming");
        adapter.addFrag(new Result(), "Result");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Using above code I am getting tab text below the icon(i mean in two different line).THe next issue is I have set the margin but I dont know how to set the color of margin.The final issue is I want to change the background color of active tab to yellow as shown in image.Please help me fix this issue

Comment: Plz provide your Output Screen..

Or Refer this :-
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: what arrangement you want?

Comment: I want horizontal arrangement just like in the above screen

Comment: sagar bro I tried the android hive one already.Its nt working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
private void setupTabIcons() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null, false);
    ((TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Tab1");
    ((ImageView) view1.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(tabIcon[0]);

    View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null, false);
    ((TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Tab2");
    ((ImageView) view2.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(tabIcon[0]);

    View view3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null, false);
    ((TextView) view3.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Tab3");
    ((ImageView) view3.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(tabIcon[0]);


    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(view1);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(view2);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(view3);
```

your custom view will look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so what about icon?

Comment: wrong first argument type inside setCompoundDrawables method

Comment: Use ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, tabIcons[0]) instead of tabIcons[0]

Comment: As per your suggestions.I am just getting the text

Comment: inflate a LinearLayout with image and text view find both views with their id
set text in the text view and image in the image view and add that custom view to the corresponding tab

Comment: If you have some time ,can you please check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361032/android-how-to-save-and-display-data-into-two-different-activity-in-android/41374656?noredirect=1#comment69960129_41374656

Answer (score 0):

1. You can Use [android:drawableLeft](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft) to display drawable on left of
   textview properly.
2. For Different backgroundColor for Different state You can use
   android:background for different color state like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14105253/1371792)

Comment: @EdwardMintus did you go through ColorStateList? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html

Comment: I did everything I could ,Its not working please help